# Setting Up Long Distance Unidirectional Wifi Antenna

Tags: wireless, distance

A neighbor has graciously offered us temporary access to their wireless for basic internet access, but we are about 100 meters apart. I have a wireless NIC, but I wanted suggestions as to the setup.

I found on a popular website where they had made a unidirectional antenna out of an old satellite dish. I found some cheap LRM-200 cable for about 0.60/ft.

But a popular online encyclopedia says that LRM-200 has a whopping .554 dB/meter loss @ 2.4GHz!!!

I have to get to my roof and part way across it to get line of sight. I'm looking at 30-40ft. So, am I looking at 20 dB loss just from the cable alone?

Do you think this setup will work? Have any better suggestions for a wireless setup?

I don't mind spending a little money, but it is temporary after all.

---

*edit*

I already have a wideband directional cell phone booster antenna on the roof any chance that would work? I think the antenna model is zBoost CANT-0042, it came bundled when I bought a zboost ZB575V

Comment: I'm not sure 20 dB is the right number there... 40 ft at 0.554 dB/m would be 6.75 dB.

Comment: Better to put the wireless adapter on the roof right next to the antenna and run a long Ethernet cable to it.

Comment: FWIW it's LMR-200, not LRM.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately the adapter is USB external, not to mention the weather....

Comment: @Thinset never mind the weather. You can relatively cheaply weatherproof an access point that's attached via ethernet instead of USB, but you can't cheaply transmit microwave radiation over long cables without losses. So, get something that you can put where you need the radio to be. Cabling is more expensive here than your wifi hardware itself!

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think this setup will work?

No, as noticed, too much cable losses. Radio wisdom is to put the receiver as close to the antenna as possible.

In your case, that's easy: Access points come with ethernet cabling, and are far smaller than the satellite dish you're planning to install, so moving it close to the dish is far more feasible than attaching the dish to your wifi device far away.

> Have any better suggestions for a wireless setup?

Yes. Don't use a satellite dish. You can't **legally** win with that!

In most countries, Wifi radiation is legally limited by measures of *EIRP*, i.e "if I had an antenna that radiates as much in every direction as mine does in the main direction, how much power would that antenna radiate?".

That means that if your wifi device previously put out the full amount it was allowed to with its antenna, and your dish has 30 dB more gain, you **must** reduce your power by 30 dB¹ –  and to the receiver at the other end (your neighbor), that looks like you just where using the original antenna, just mounted on a roof. For you, it looks a little better: you receive your neighbor's wifi with 30 dB more power. Sadly, that alone doesn't help, because wifi and the internet requires the link to be about as good in both directions.

Unless your neighbor does the same: antennas work reciprocal, so he gets 30 dB more from your direction – and since you also get 30 dB more, you've increased your link budget by 30 dB.

But: this requires highly directional antennas on both ends; a situation where you still win, even if both of you have to reduce output power.

What you should try alternatively is really just throwing cheap access points (ebay!) with low-gain antennas on top of your roofs, so that they have line of sight, and place them e.g. in plastic buckets (with holes for ethernet cabling, and slight air exchange – you don't want condensation). That's a < 50 USD solution, and worth a try.

---

¹ "but, that's totally annoying! How should anyone have far reach with an ISM band device then?" I hear you cry: That's the whole point. You're ruining the band for other people in the beam of your dish, and that's why you're not allowed to do that.

Comment: ummm, access point, bucket, cat6. got it, thanks.